# No funciona dbms_output.put_line en SQL Developer

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-10g

En una base de datos 10g no me está mostrando la salida con este código ejecutando en SQL Developer

**SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

begin

dbms_output.put_line('Entra');

end;**

¿Alguna idea de por qué? En una base de datos 19 si funciona.

Gracias y un saludo.

Fernan.

Comment: en view fiaje si esta activado el dbmsoutput.

Comment: Las últimas versiones de SQLDeveloper no parecen soportar dbms_output en versiones viejas del server. También trabajo con una BBDD en 10g y tuve que descargar la versión 4.2.0 para poder utilizar el output.

Comment: Buenas: 
Bryro: Si, claro.
Roberto: Gracias. Seguiré con del SQL Navigator.

Gracias a los dos.
Fernan.